# Using parent.XRM + removal of the ClientGlobalContext.js.aspx

Tags: dynamics-crm, microsoft-dynamics, dynamics-365, power-platform, dynamics-365-sales

Please I need input on deprecation of ClientGlobalContext.js.aspx according to the below article. We are using parent.Xrm in standalone web resource for an integration. I am confused about "window.parent.Xrm.WebApi.online.****" will these sort of sdk methods still work. According to: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/power-platform/important-changes-coming:

*"Including a reference to ClientGlobalContext.js.aspx does not make the Xrm object available in HTML web resources. Therefore, scripts containing Xrm.* methods aren’t supported in HTML web resources. parent.Xrm.* will work if the HTML web resource is loaded in a form container. However, for other places, such as loading an HTML web resource as part of the SiteMap, parent.Xrm.* also won’t work."*

So parent.Xrm won't work but what about window.parent.Xrm being used in a HTML web resource as part of the SiteMap/standalone html web resource.

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powerapps/developer/model-driven-apps/clientapi/reference/getglobalcontext-clientglobalcontext.js.aspx

Would appreciate some clarification.

Answer (score 0):

Update: Looks like OP opened a [GitHub issue](https://github.com/MicrosoftDocs/powerapps-docs/issues/3041) and coincidently Microsoft made some decisions on reversing the deprecation announcement. Good news!

> We are moving the timeline out for deprecating this feature. There is currently no ETA so you can expect to continue to use ClientGlobalContext.js.aspx. We are in the process of updating the docs to remove the deprecation announcement.

---

If you are in process of developing new customizations, then it is recommended to go with PCF control or custom page development. I share your pain and Microsoft is working on this, these deprecations/support removal is planned for good and replacements are getting announced frequently. [Read more](https://dianabirkelbach.wordpress.com/2021/09/29/goodbye-html-web-resources/)

If this is about redevelopment of many existing web resources in your orgs, then plan for it slowly - this will be a trouble eventually.

Comment: I added that question in Github :)

Comment: @Noor yes you're the OP (original poster) :)